# How to collect into TreeMap in stream?

Tags: java, java-stream, treemap

I have two `Collectors.groupingBy` in Stream. And I need to collect all information to `TreeMap`.

My Code:

```
Map<LocalDate, Map<String, List<RollingField>>> fieldMap = rollingFields.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
            RollingField::getDate,
            Collectors.groupingBy(fi -> fi.getMeta().getName())));
```

And this return `HashMap`. What i need to add for returning `TreeMap`? I need this for sorting by `LocalDate`.

Comment: `Collectors::groupingBy` has an overload method that does exactly what you need

Comment: give the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the specific method that allows to provide a `Map` factory through `Supplier` that is
 [`Collectors.groupingBy(Function<..> classifier, Supplier<M> mapFactory, Collector<..> downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) where:

- `classifier` maps elements into keys
- `mapFactory` produces a new empty map (here you use `() -> new TreeMap<>()`)
- `downstream` the downstream reduction

Implementation:

```
Map<LocalDate, Map<String, List<RollingField>>> fieldMap = rollingFields.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
                RollingField::getDate,                // outer Map keys
                TreeMap::new,                         // outer Map is TreeMap
                Collectors.groupingBy(                // outer Map values
                        fi -> fi.getMeta().getName(), // inner Map keys
                        TreeMap::new,                 // inner Map is TreeMap
                        Collectors.toList()           // inner Map values (default)
                )
        ));
```

Don't worry that there is no such overloaded method like `Collectors.groupingBy(Function<..> classifier, Supplier<M> mapFactory)` without `downstream`. The default implementation of `downstream` is collecting to List, therefore free to reuse it (`Collectors.toList()`), from the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-):

> This produces a result similar to: `groupingBy(classifier, toList());`